# How can I remove the last part?

Tags: c#, string, split

I'd like to split this:

```
0, 250, 6, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 0,
```

I tried:

```
words = poly[a].Split(charseparators);

    foreach (string word in words)

    {
      richTextBox1.Text += (d + 1)+ " " + word+ "\r\n";
     d++;
     }
```

this is not the full code, but the problem is: it should look like this :

```
18 70

19 70

20 0
```

but it looks like this:

```
18 70

19 70

20 0

21
```

there's an extra part, because at the end of the last word, there's always a ',' 
how could i remove the last line?

code:

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        int size = -1;
        string text = "";

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }

        }
        int a = 0;
        int b =1;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(file);
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Pacs_Parad//Pac_Parameter_Set//Pac_Zuo_Pave_Para");
        XmlNodeList polygon = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Polygon_CS_List");
        XmlNodeList value = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Value");
        XmlNodeList synonym = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Synonym_Name");
        XmlNodeList typeflag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Type_Flag");
        string[] poly = new string[polygon.Count];
        foreach(XmlNode node in polygon)
        {
            poly[a] = node.InnerText;
            a++;
        }
        a = 0;
        string[] tf = new string[size];

        foreach (XmlNode node in typeflag)
        {
            tf[a] = node.InnerText;
            a++;
        }
        a = 0;

       richTextBox1.Multiline = true;
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        string[]words = null;
        char[] charseparators = new char[] { ',' };
        for (int i = 0; i <synonym.Count; i++)
        {

           richTextBox1.Text += b + "." + " Name: " + synonym[i].InnerText + "\r\n" +
                                          " Type: "  ;


                if (tf[i] == "P")
                {
                richTextBox1.Text += "Polygon  " + "\r\n";
                     words = poly[a].Split(charseparators);
                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text += (d + 1)+ " " + word+ "\r\n";
                        d++;
                    }
                    d = 0;

                    a++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tf[i] == "C")
                    {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Constant  " + "\r\n";
                    richTextBox1.Text += "value: " + value[c].InnerText + "\r\n";
                            c++;

                    }

                }
            richTextBox1.Text += "\r\n";



            b++;


        }





    }
```

Comment: How about using `.RTrim(',')` before splitting?

Comment: It still doesn't work as i wanted to, and I still don't understand why....

Comment: What does "not work as I wanted to" mean? You still have the extra entry? have you impolemented any of the suggestions? If so: which? And where?

Comment: i tried all of these things what you guys wrote, i really thanks, but none of them worked, yeah i still had that extra 21, but i tried it with trim in my ways, and it worked 






                                                                                                                           words = poly[a].Split(charseparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (string word in words)
                        {   
                            richTextBox1.Text += (d + 1)+ "  " + word.Trim(',')+ "\r\n";
                            d++;

Comment: The correct way to trim would be `words = poly[a].TrimEnd(charseparators).Split(charseparators);` before your `foreach`

Comment: Why would that be the correct way, and not just removing empty entries?

Comment: @CallumLinington the correct way _to trim_ I said. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
words = poly[a].Split(charseparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Where the `Split` overload using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will make sure that it will remove all the empty array elements.

This is dependent on what type `charseparators` is, if it is an array of `char` the overload operator will be available. If not you just need to put it into one:

```
words = poly[a].Split(new [] { charseparators }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

### Performance trimming vs splitting

As an interesting aside:

```
var str = "0, 250, 6, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 0,";

var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    str.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

timer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Spliting took: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    str.Trim(',').Split(',');
}

timer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Trimming then Spliting took: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
```

This test comes back with the results:

```
Spliting took: 810ms
Trimming then Spliting took: 570ms
```

**Noticable** at only > 10,000 interations where the results were:

```
Spliting took: 7ms
Trimming then Spliting took: 5ms
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line to remove the last to characters which is `\r` and `\n`

```
if(words.Length > 0)
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Lenght - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If empty entrys are allowed in your string, you can not use

```
words = poly[a].Split(charseparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`
```

because this would remove such entries aswell. I would trim the seperator at the end.

```
words = poly[a].Split(charseparators.TrimEnd(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove empty entries via `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
 richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, poly[a]
    .Split(charseparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select((value, index) => String.Format("{0} {1}", index + 1, value.Trim())));
```

To prevent `richTextBox1` from *blinking* try avoiding

```
richTextBox1.Text += ... // <- this is a bad parctice
```

but assign the text value in *one go* (e.g. via `string.Join`)